# Sending notifications to users in web applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am developing a Cafeteria Management System using Django (my first project in web-development, so yes I am a beginner) in which there are two kind of users **"Counter Staff" & "customers"**.

Now, the current order's list is shown as table on the counter side. On the customer's side, there is a table that displays current available dishes.

There are two types of events:-

1. Customer orders the food.
2. Counter enables/disables a dish as per availability.

So, if the customer orders food, I want the table at the counter side to be added
For the second event, if counter enables/disables a dish, I want the customer's side table to add/remove dish row.

I want a real-time solution. So, how do I implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long polling is a preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need both users to poll the server.  Use timers in your JavaScript to make requests to the server (this is called polling) every minute or so.  Then use jQuery's great traversal and manipulation utilities to rebuild the tables in the browser.

Or if you don't want to implement updating the view using JavaScript and prefer to stick with the view rendering you have with Django..

Have an endpoint on the server that returns the last time a dish was added or removed.  Have a timer that compares that time with the time the page was rendered.  If a dish has been added or removed, refresh the page via JavaScript.  If you do this, don't compare the client time with the server time.  You'll need to embed the server time in the page as a JavaScript variable.

Comment: I am not able to understand the way you told me of implementing without javascript. From what I understand, there is nothing django can do, once the page is loaded. I am new to django so may be I dont know the full functionality.

Comment: Django is rendering the page already, so you can use JavaScript to find out if the page is "dirty", then use JavaScript to re-request the page from the server (a.k.a., Django).  Make sense?  I don't recommend this approach because it requires a round-trip to the server, and denies you the benefits of a lightweight AJAX-enabled web app

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at signals:

[Django Sisgnals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/)